# QGIS: intersect and filter in expression based filter

Tags: qgis, intersection, filter, aggregation, qgis-expression

I am trying to filter as part of an intersection but can't work out where to add the filter.

The intersection works fine
`intersects($geometry,aggregate('DSC_Roads','collect',$geometry))`

But where can I add `filter:="owner" in ('Private','Council')` to only work on the 'DSC_Roads' layer when the owner column is in ('Private', 'Council')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almoste there - add the filter as last argument of the `aggregate()` function. According to [help for aggregate()](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#aggregate), the syntax looks like:

> ```
> aggregate(layer, aggregate, expression, [filter], [concatenator=’’], [order_by])
> ```
>
> [] marks optional arguments

Thus the  expression must look like:

```
intersects(
    $geometry,
    aggregate(
        'DSC_Roads',
        'collect',
        $geometry, 
        filter:="owner" in ('Private','Council')
    )
)
```

*Only polygons with `owner` attribute value = `'Private'` or `'Council'` are selected:*
[image]